# How to set Durable Subscriber in DefaultMessageListenerContainer in spring?

Tags: jms, spring-jms, amq

Producer of the message is not sending message as persistent and when i am trying to consume the message through MessageListener, and any exception(runtime) occurs, it retries for specific number of times (default is 6 from AMQ side) and message get lost.

Reason is that since producer is not setting the Delivery mode as Persistent, after certain number of retry attempt, DLQ is not being created and message does not move to DLQ. Due to this , i lost the message.

My Code is like this :-

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ActiveMqJmsConfig {

@Autowired
private AbcMessageListener abcMessageListener;

public DefaultMessageListenerContainer purchaseMsgListenerforAMQ(
    @Qualifier("AMQConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory amqConFactory) {

    LOG.info("Message listener for purchases from AMQ : Starting");
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer =
        new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();

    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(amqConFactory);

    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(4);

    defaultMessageListenerContainer
        .setDestinationName(purchaseReceivingQueueName);

    defaultMessageListenerContainer
        .setMessageListener(abcMessageListener);

    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);

    return defaultMessageListenerContainer;
}

 @Bean
@Qualifier(value = "AMQConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();

    amqConnectionFactory
        .setBrokerURL(System.getProperty(tcp://localhost:61616));
    amqConnectionFactory
        .setUserName(System.getProperty(admin));
    amqConnectionFactory
        .setPassword(System.getProperty(admin));

    return amqConnectionFactory;

}

}

@Component
public class AbcMessageListener implements MessageListener {
 @Override
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
//CODE implementation
}

}
```

Problem :- By setting the client-id at connection level (Connection.setclientid("String")), we can subscribe as durable subscriber even though message is not persistent. By doing this, if application throws runtime exception  , after a certain number of retry attempt, DLQ will be created for the Queue and message be moved to DLQ.

But in DefaultMessageListenerContainer, connection is not exposed to client. it is maintained by Class itself as a pool, i guess.

How can i achieve the durable subscription in DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the client id on the container instead:

```
/**
 * Specify the JMS client ID for a shared Connection created and used
 * by this container.
 * <p>Note that client IDs need to be unique among all active Connections
 * of the underlying JMS provider. Furthermore, a client ID can only be
 * assigned if the original ConnectionFactory hasn't already assigned one.
 * @see javax.jms.Connection#setClientID
 * @see #setConnectionFactory
 */
public void setClientId(@Nullable String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Set the name of a durable subscription to create. This method switches
 * to pub-sub domain mode and activates subscription durability as well.
 * <p>The durable subscription name needs to be unique within this client's
 * JMS client id. Default is the class name of the specified message listener.
 * <p>Note: Only 1 concurrent consumer (which is the default of this
 * message listener container) is allowed for each durable subscription,
 * except for a shared durable subscription (which requires JMS 2.0).
 * @see #setPubSubDomain
 * @see #setSubscriptionDurable
 * @see #setSubscriptionShared
 * @see #setClientId
 * @see #setMessageListener
 */
public void setDurableSubscriptionName(@Nullable String durableSubscriptionName) {
    this.subscriptionName = durableSubscriptionName;
    this.subscriptionDurable = (durableSubscriptionName != null);
}
```

Comment: Setting client id at DMLC will not set the same client id for all connection if auto-scaling happpens ? I tried this but it did not create the DLQ after getting poison message

Comment: You can't "auto scale" when consuming from a topic, the concurrency must be one; otherwise each consumer will get a copy of the message, unless you are using JMS 2.0 and shared durable subscriptions.

Comment: But i will not be directly consuming from Virtual Topic. I will be consuming from Queue which is attached to Virtual Topic. Only issue i had that if producer to Virtual Topic is not persistent message, how will i make DLQ in consumer side (Queue side) if i get poison message and message moves to DLQ .

Comment: Sorry - that is a question about AMQ, not spring; I can't answer that.